# Has anyone built their own progress bar on top of jquery validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, progress-bar

It seems like the validator is already doing all the work to know how far a form is filled out.  So I just want to tie that into a progress bar.

It would also be nice in a multi-form scenario that I can tell it how much is already down from previous forms...

Answer (score 2):

jQuery validate throws a class of `valid` when something passes validation.

Just get quick count of them, fire it off every couple seconds, or maybe on any blur event of a textbox.

[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/R49hh/)

```
var progressInterval = setInterval(function () {

    var progress = $('.required.valid').length,
        total    = $('.required').length;

    $('#progress').html('Progress: ' + progress + ' / ' + total);

}, 1000);
```

Comment: The valid class might help me count.  But I'm hoping not to have to put blur event's on all the textboxes, radio buttons, select lists, etc.  Since validate is already hooking into everything it would be nice to leverage that completely.  Plus there might be other javascript that change field values and then call valid, etc.

Comment: Just have it in an `interval` updating itself every second real fast and updating then. Real easy! Just updated it with a Demo, works great.

Comment: It looks to work well enough.Thx.

Comment: Yeah it's basic, you can add more stuff, fill in a div with color or something %-wise. Whole lot of options from there.

Comment: Also Mark as correct if the answer helps :)